# Can I save my web app data to facebook using javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm starting to use facebook graph api for a simple web project.
And my web project is something like this:
- People log-in using facebook
- I'll use their facebook data to put their profile details on my website (using javascript)
- Now, my website has a simple game which when it ends, will give a corresponding score to the user. I need to be able to save the score to facebook so everytime a user comes to my site again, they will see their score history.

I know I could do that using PHP/MySQL but I need to do it using only javscript,html, and css.
Thanks! :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/ is probably what you want

Comment: scores api by facebook may seem nice, but what if I need to store strings? Thank you, but I what I really want is to how I could save data to facebook from my web app.

Comment: You can't, you can post content from your app to Facebook but Facebook doesn't act as a storage mechanism for you - you'd need an actual database for that